# Verification code rather than url in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback as an api for a phone app.

How could I change the out of the box verification of an email address when a user signs up. I need it to be a 4 digit code (instead of a url) so that it's more friendly to the user verifying their account inside the app.

ie. they would then just need to enter the 4 digit number to confirm the registration

Comment: I think you could just overwrite the default verification generation method, but I've never tried... I'll see if I can work up an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but it basically comes down to overriding [the `user.verify()`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L328-L402) method (or some portion of it). If you click on that link above and scroll down just a bit you'll see how LoopBack is using the `crypto.randomBytes()` method to generate the `verificationToken` which is stored on the user object, then it emails it to the user. We can override this method in a "submodel" which extends `user` and then implement it ourselves, but note that you would be copying a lot of that information.

That said, I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/1205) to LoopBack to make this easier. Check out that link and you can see how it *might* be done in the future (if the PR doesn't change).

For now, you would have to override the `verify()` method:

```
User.prototype.verify = function(options, fn) {
  var user = this;

  // do a lot of audits and other stuff (check the current source)...

  // Set the token any way you like...
  user.verificationToken = "123456"; // <-- this probably isn't a good way
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      fn(err);
    } else {
      sendEmail(user);
    }
  });

  function sendEmail(user) {
    // you should be able to keep this exactly as it is in the source...
  }
};
```

And of course, don't forget to read about [verifying user email addresses](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Registering+users) in the LoopBack documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [pass the token generation function](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L374-L378) to the options object. You can see [how it's used if you scroll down a bit](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L439-L452).

[Check my answer to a somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821955/767676) for steps on how to override the User model and pass the options object to the `verify()` method.

You can do this in the remote hook after you create a new User, e.g.:

```
User.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
    var userModel = User.constructor;

    myTokenGenerator = function(user, cb) {
      myToken = '1234'
      cb(null, myToken);
    };

    var options = {
      type: 'email',
      mailer: Email,
      to: user.email,
      from: senderEmail,
      subject: 'My subject',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/verify.ejs'),
      user: user,
      host: myEmailHost,
      port: myEmailPort,
      generateVerificationToken: myTokenGenerator
    };

    user.verify(options, function(err, response) {

      if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Account verification email sent to " + options.to);
      next();
      return;
    });
});
```